# How can I change the TexMaker interface language?

Tags: texmaker, languages

Turns out my PC thinks it's Italian... any way, the TexMaker interface is, for some unknown reason, suddenly in Italian and I don't speak a word (I would love to, thou). Can anyone guide me through the interface language setting ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Go to `Options`-->`Interface Language`--> select `en` for english.

Comment: @texenthusiast Where is the answer? ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple, Just Go to `Options`-->`Interface Language`--> select `en` for english as shown below

[image]