# How do I change the spellcheck language of Texmaker to US English?

Tags: texmaker, mac, spelling, locale

I've installed Texmaker (via MacTeX using Homebrew) and noticed that the spell checker has been set to British English. Thus is marks "color" as a misspelling and suggests "colour" as an alternative.

How can I switch Texmaker to use US English as the language of the spellchecker? (It would be even better if I could get it to use the same spellchecking library as the rest of macOS so that my learned spellings will be applied).

Related, but not duplicate:

- [TexMaker: switch dictionary / language confortably](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213306/189731), which is concerned about per-document dictionaries. I would like to change the global dictionary.
- [How can I change the TexMaker interface language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170813/189731), which is about changing the user interface language, but not the spellchecker (my interface language is already set to "en").

Comment: @santimirandarp Where would I download it? Is it in some sort of special format?

Answer (score 1):

Choose "Option" in the menu line, then "Configure Texmaker". Click on the icon on the left side marked "Editor", and you will see the following:

[image]

Click on the icon besides en_GB and chose en_US from the file lists.

[image]

Double click on the file or click "Open". Then click "OK" on the next dialogue box to save the new setting.

Comment: Hmm, the folder doesn't contain `en_US`. It has `en_GB.dic` and other non-English languages like `de_DE.dic`, `es_ES.dic`, `fr_FR.dic`, etc. Do I have to download those on my own?

Comment: If you have Acrobat Reader installed, it will normally have a en_US spelling dictionary. You can copy those files from Acrobat folder to the Texmaker folder and restart Texmaker. Copy both the .dic and .aff

Answer (score 0):

ALL Texmaker installers (even portable version) include lots of language files, So you should have a README_en_US.txt and 2011 version of en_US.aff and dic in the Texmaker folders if not then I would check if the installer was a legitimate one the latest version in 2019 should be 5.0.3 but it still includes the 2011 Hunspell dictionaries for en_US see below for a source of newer files

I understand that some mac users have had some similar issues with spell checker behaviour in various editors such as you describe. so it may be interference or over-riding duplicate sets of en_gb files thus it may not be a Texmaker issue but a wider mac settings issue.

> It is possible to set a language per TeX file so add the following as
>   your first few lines and see what is respected
>
> ```
> % !TeX spellcheck = en_US 
> % or en_GB to test on file reload remove the % at start of next 3 lines to check which ones are NOT underlined in red
> % color (US) = colour (UK)
> % pasteurize = pasteurise
> % favorite   = favourite 
> \documentclass{...
> ```

Note

If my locale.dic is US and file is US then the **UK spelling is underlined** as suspect for correction to color etc. (expected)
If my locale.dic is GB and file is US then the **UK spelling is underlined** as suspect for correction to color etc. (expected)
If my locale.dic is US and file is GB then **NO spelling is underlined** as suspect for correction which I half expected BUT perhaps should not (see next test)
If my locale.dic is GB and file is GB then NO spelling is underlined as suspect for correction which was **unexpected HOWEVER** as color is a major part of TeX either I in the past or Texmaker has decided it is a misspelling to be ignored. **BUT pasteurize SHOULD BE underlined** THUS I see initially an OPPOSITE PROBLEM since **ize is not underlined but if I add favorite it behaves as expected so it is the only reliable test**

**Anywhere else in my UK system then US spellings are the one I see underlined**

2018/2019 files

Every couple/few months the Hunspell en dictionaries are updated and released via OpenOffice or Libre Office updates 
https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice or https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries  both sets are *usually* the same content

Here the latest Open Office with US content from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html (16th April 2018) was released a 2nd(b) time after 2019:05:01   https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/node/17102/releases

The file with an .oxt extension may be used direct by some editors whilst others need it renamed to .ZIP and the individual content extracted see the following **zip folder contents**.

[image]

Texmaker only needs 3 of the US files
Readme_en_US.txt
en_US.aff
en_us.dic

Comment: Could you please clarify what OpenOffice has to do with LaTex? I thought that was an equivalent to Microsoft Office.

Comment: @Thunderforge Texmaker uses the same dictionaries as OpenOffice and LibreOffice. You have to rename the .oxt to .zip, unpack it and copy the file to Texmaker's directory for dictionaries. The _hyph-files are not that important since they are not used by Texmaker.